# R Shiny pickerInput select all text

Tags: r, shiny

Using shinywidgets pickerinput I am trying to use a dropdown. Below is the code. Could someone tell me how to display the text total in the display input when then user selects all inputs.I can show the count but not the text total instead.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "id", label = "Choices :",
      choices = c("Banana", "Blueberry", "Cherry", "Coconut", "Grapefruit",
                  "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Lime", "Mango", "Orange", "Papaya"),
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `selected-text-format` = "count > 2",
                     `count-selected-text` = "{0}/{1} fruits"),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$id
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Add `textOutput("res")` somewhere in your ui portion. You're not telling your app to show anything other than the `pickerInput()` call as it is.

Comment: I want to see total inside the select picker text box (the dropdown) instead of seeing it outside. When you run the code and select none it says nothing selected. But when it says select total it show individual items and not as 'total'

Answer (score 8):

Something like this?

Edit: as per request `I just want the text "TOTAL" when everything is selected`:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

mychoices <- c("Banana", "Blueberry", "Cherry", "Coconut", "Grapefruit","Kiwi", "Lemon", "Lime", "Mango", "Orange", "Papaya")
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "id", label = "Choices :",
      choices = mychoices,
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(mychoices)),`count-selected-text` = "TOTAL"),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: If I click on select all can I just show total instead of count.

Comment: Please draw a picture what you want in that field

Comment: From the image you have put, I just want the text "TOTAL" when everything is selected.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got the code above to work; I believe there's a typo with paste0, and there would never be a case where the count was greater than the total number of options available. But a few small modifications to the options line worked for me. ```options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `selected-text-format` = paste0("count > ", length(mychoices) -1),`count-selected-text` = "TOTAL")```