# How to display All when everything is selected in pickerinput

Tags: r, shiny

Below code works fine, the only add-on I want is to  display "All"  when everything is selected and the rest works as it is, that is if 1 option is selected it show show 1/11 fruits and so on. Can anyone help me with this?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "id", label = "Choices :",
      choices = c("Banana", "Blueberry", "Cherry", "Coconut", "Grapefruit",
                  "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Lime", "Mango", "Orange", "Papaya"),
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, `selected-text-format` = "count > 0",
                     `count-selected-text` = "{0}/{1} fruits"),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$id
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shiny pickerInput select all text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616346/r-shiny-pickerinput-select-all-text)

Comment: @sada93 The problem  is still not solved in this link

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full capabilities of shiny widgets, but this can certainly be achieved by sending information from the server back to the UI though custom messages. Here is how I did it, albeit it does look kinda hacky.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(
    width = 4,
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "id", label = "Choices :",
      choices = c("Banana", "Blueberry", "Cherry", "Coconut", "Grapefruit",
                  "Kiwi", "Lemon", "Lime", "Mango", "Orange", "Papaya"),
      options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, 
                     `selected-text-format` = "count > 0",
                     `count-selected-text` = "{0}/{1} fruits"
                     ),
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  ),
  singleton({
    tags$head(tags$script(
      "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(\"testmessage\",
                                    function(message) {
                                    var x = document.getElementsByClassName(\"filter-option pull-left\");
                                    x[0].innerHTML = message;
                                    }
      );"
    ))
  })
)


server <- function(input,output,session) {
  output$res <- renderPrint({
    input$id
  })

  numOptions = 11

  observe({
    if(length(input$id) == numOptions){
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                                message = list("All"))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here I check if all the elements are chosen in an observer in the server function. If they are, I trigger a simple javascript function on the UI.

Comment: this still gives the same result as previous

Comment: Did you clear your environment, and run the whole script? When you select all the elements it shows "All" in the select input.

Comment: Yes I did, but the result is same

Comment: Testing it on Chome? What version of shiny, shinyWidgets are you using?

Comment: Yes testing on Chrome and version of shiny is 1.2.0 and shiny widgets is 0.4.4